# Is there an easier way to find the order of all the elements of group $(\mathbb{Z}/16 \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$?

Tags: group-theory

I have the multiplicative group of integers modulo 16, $G = (\mathbb{Z}/16 \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$

I know that is has the elements ${1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15}$, as these are the only numbers that are relatively prime to $16$.

So it has order $8$. Using Lagrange's Theorem I only have to check the orders $1,2,4,8$ for each element, as these are the only possible orders the elements can have. This however is still a cumbersome process to do for every single element.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: @Dzoooks I don't think that this group is cyclic.

Comment: In any group, an element and its inverse have the same order, so that cuts down the work somewhat. But seriously, you find it hard to take powers of $8$ elements? Did you even try, or are you complaining before you do any of the computational work?

Answer (score 2):

There is not much to do: Write under each element $g$ its square mod $16$. Chasing through the resulting table it is then easy to read off the order of each $g$.
$$\eqalign{&1\quad 3\quad5\quad 7\quad9\quad 11\quad13\quad15 \cr
&1\quad 9\quad9\quad 1\quad1\quad \ 9\quad\ \ 9\quad\ \ 1 \cr}$$